# GIMP eyedropper returning wrong colors

Tags: gimp

I seem to have an odd issue with GIMP. Since two days, if I try to pick a color with the color picker, GIMP returns a wrong (and seemingly arbitrary) color. The color selection tool already looks broken:

[image]

If I now try to select the dark blue in the center of the image, the color it selects is completely wrong:

[image]

I have tried reinstalling GIMP, to little avail. I made sure the image is in RGB, and I reset the color management preferences. Any idea what causes the issue, and how to fix it? I am using GIMP 2.10.8 on Windows 10.

Edit: As requested, an image of the color picker tool options:
[image]

Comment: Any layers? What are the options on the color picker tool?

Comment: Yes, that image above is on its own layers. I'll attach an image of the color picker tool options.

Comment: Strange. What color reports the [Pointer dialog](https://docs.gimp.org/en/gimp-pointer-info-dialog.html)?

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. What happens if you select "Sample merged"?

Comment: Thanks for the answers - xenoid: the pointer dialog reports the correct colors; Billy Kerr: If I select "Sample merged", the issue still persists; Rob: There are overlaps - the color picker does indeed return the correct color, but the eyedropped when selecting the foreground (or background) color does not

Comment: Can you post a sample XCF somewhere?

Comment: Hmm . . that's interesting. However, I'm unable to replicate the problem. When I choose the eyedropper tool in the Change Foreground Color dialog window, it seems to work just fine. The colour sampled is the same as indicated by the Color Picker tool.  It sounds like there might be some file-specific problem, perhaps something to do with the way the image was constructed?